# Non-commutative Algebra $LM=t^2 ML$, using NCAlgebra/Mathematica

Tags: symbolic, algebra, ncalgebra

I am currently using the NCAlgebra package, and am working with the algebra where $LM=t^2 ML$, where t is commutative.

```
SetNonCommutative[L,M]
SetCommutative[t]

rule:=L**M -> t^2 M**L
NCReplaceAll[L**M, rule]
```

> t^2 M**L

```
NCReplaceRepeated[L**M^2, L**M -> t^2 M**L]
```

> t^2 M**L**M

```
NCReplaceRepeated[NCReplaceRepeated[L**M^2, rule], rule]
```

> t^4 M**M**L

I was wondering if there was a way for me to easily have the package show that $LM^2=t^4M^2L$. (I thought the NCReplaceRepeated should have done this, but for me it was not doing so, as shown in the picture.)

In the end I will be wanting to work with polynomials in t,M, and L. And will want to simplify/expand the multiplication of such polynomials.

For example have that, $a(M)L^k \cdot b(M)L^n = a(M)b(t^{2k}M)L^{k+n}$, where $a(M)$ and $b(M)$ are polynomials.

Also if possible, I would like to have $M**M=M^2$(and the same for $L$).

Any help/tips would be greatly apreciated.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32229/simplifying-polynomials-in-non-commutative-variables

Comment: The above link introduces FeynCalc, which I am liking so far. I have gotten to do the things I have wanted, and will continue to play with it.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Disclaimer:  I'm thoroughly unfamiliar with `NCAlgebra`, but I thought this question was a good excuse to take a look.  I have done a fair amount of monkeying around with `NonCommutativeMultiply` on my own.</sub>

---

First, notice that `NCAlgebra` removes the attribute `Flat` from `NonCommutativeMultiply` (in fact, all of `NonCommutativeMultiply`'s attributes are removed).

Let's take a look at what actually happens in the evaluation of `NCReplaceRepeated`.  We can query

```
?? NCReplaceRepeated
```

> ```
> NCReplaceAll[NCReplace`Private`expr_,NCReplace`Private`rule_]:=
>   ReplaceAll@@({NCReplace`Private`expr,NCReplace`Private`rule}/.   
>     NCReplace`Private`NCReplaceFlatRules)/. 
>     NCReplace`Private`NCReplaceReverseFlatRules
> ```

If you're unfamiliar with packages and contexts, `` NCReplace`Private`symbolName `` just means it's a 'private' symbol in the `NCReplace` package -- that is, a symbol the user doesn't usually need, and hence its name is hidden.  (More properly, it's a symbol which belongs to a different [`Context`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Context.html), but I won't get into that.)

In any case, let's first look at the values of `` NCReplace`Private`NCReplaceFlatRules `` and `` NCReplace`Private`NCReplaceReverseFlatRules `` :

```
NCReplace`Private`NCReplaceFlatRules
```

> ```
> {NonCommutativeMultiply -> NCReplace`Private`FlatNCMultiply}
> ```

```
NCReplace`Private`NCReplaceReverseFlatRules
```

> ```
> {NCReplace`Private`FlatNCMultiply -> NonCommutativeMultiply}
> ```

```
? NCReplace`Private`FlatNCMultiply
```

> ```
> Attributes[NCReplace`Private`FlatNCMultiply]={Flat,OneIdentity}
> ```

```
? NonCommutativeMultiply
```

> ```
> (* No attributes mentioned *)
> ```

Ah, ok.  First, note that before loading `NCAlgebra`, `NonCommutativeMultiply` had attributes `{Flat, OneIdentity, Protected}`.  `NCAlgebra` (kind of) mentions this in the [docs](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ncalg/DOCUMENTATION/index.html#fn3) :

> The reason is that making an operator Flat is a convenience that comes with a price: lack of control over execution and evaluation. Since NCAlgebra has to operate at a very low level this lack of control over evaluation is fatal. Indeed, making NonCommutativeMultiply have an attribute Flat will throw Mathematica into infinite loops in seemingly trivial noncommutative expression. Hey, email us if you find a way around that :)

If you're unsure what the [`Flat`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flat.html) attribute does, the `NCAlgebra` docs have a good explanation in this context at the start of section 5.1.

As the package mentions, problems (apparently, though believably) occur when a symbol has both `Flat` attribute and `NCAlgebra`'s built-in definitions for dealing with commutative/non-commutative symbols.  One such rule is the one that pulls powers of `t` out of `NonCommutativeMultiply` :

```
L ** t^2 ** M
```

> ```
> t^2 L ** M
> ```

The whole point is that this *can't* happen automatically in `` NCReplace`Private`FlatNCMultiply ``, because of the `Flat` attribute.  Why does this matter?  Because what `NCReplaceRepeated` is doing is precisely replacing all instances of `NonCommutativeMultiply` (both in the expression you're replacing and the replacement rules themselves) with `` NCReplace`Private`FlatNCMultiply ``, and then replacing back to `NonCommutativeMultiply` at the end.

Let's take a look at what happens if we do this process ourselves:

```
L ** M^2 /. NCReplace`Private`NCReplaceFlatRules
```

> ```
> NCReplace`Private`FlatNCMultiply[L, M, M]
> ```

```
% /. (L ** M -> t^2 M ** L /. NCReplace`Private`NCReplaceFlatRules)
```

> ```
> NCReplace`Private`FlatNCMultiply[ t^2 NCReplace`Private`FlatNCMultiply[M, L], M]
> ```

```
% /. NCReplace`Private`NCReplaceReverseFlatRules
```

> ```
> t^2 M ** L ** M
> ```

We can see the issue in the second-to-last step:  the `t^2` prevents `` NCReplace`Private`FlatNCMultiply `` from flattening -- the flattening only occurs after converting back to `NonCommutativeMultiply`.
This is the reason why applying `NCReplaceRepeated` a second time works -- everything is flattened out by the end of the first call, allowing the replacement to happen in the second call.

---

## What can we do about it?

### Quick and dirty

Note that

```
NCReplaceRepeated[L ** M ** M, A___ ** L ** M ** B___ :> t^2 A ** M ** L ** B]
```

> t^4 M ** M ** L

works right away.  Of course, this requires putting all your rules into such a 'non-flat' form manually.  You could try to automate that, but the following method is hopefully more robust.

### More elegant solution

We can define our own function:

```
ClearAll@NCreallyReplaceRepeated
NCreallyReplaceRepeated[expr_, rule_] :=
  FixedPoint[ NCReplaceRepeated[#, rule] &, expr]

NCreallyReplaceRepeated[L ** M ** M, L ** M -> t^2 M ** L]
```

> ```
> t^4 M ** M ** L
> ```

#### Small caveat

Note that the above involves doing the exact same ReplaceAll on the transformation rules themselves within each iteration of `FixedPoint`.  Usually this is fine, though it could be the bottleneck for very long rules.  To avoid this, I recommend instead:

```
ClearAll@NCreallyReplaceRepeated2
NCreallyReplaceRepeated2[expr_, rule_] :=
 With[{ruleTrans = rule /. NCReplace`Private`NCReplaceFlatRules},
  FixedPoint[
   ReplaceAll[NCReplace`Private`NCReplaceReverseFlatRules]
    @*(ReplaceRepeated[#, ruleTrans] &)
    @*ReplaceAll[NCReplace`Private`NCReplaceFlatRules],
   expr]
  ]

NCreallyReplaceRepeated2[L ** M ** M, L ** M -> t^2 M ** L]
```

> ```
> t^4 M ** M ** L
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your careful analysis of the problem. This is better dealt with by adding an additional rule to the private FlatNCMultiply. I have added that in the latest release of NCAlgebra.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this in v5.0.4 of NCAlgebra. Please upgrade.

Comment: I am still having this issue in $5.0.4$ with NCRR. I am new to the package, though, so it might be on my end.

Comment: There's a new question on NCAlgebra: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/182194/12

Comment: @ElliotG can you be more specific? You can email me or post it here if you think it is a bug.