# NCAlgebra to Mathematica Standard form

Tags: ncalgebra

Is there any way to convert the output of [NCAlgebra](https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC) to standard Mathematica form?

For example

```
<< NC`

<< NCAlgebra`

MatrixForm[m = {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}}];
NCInverse[m][[1, 1]]
```

The output is

```
    a^(-1) ** (1 - b ** (e - d ** a^(-1) ** b)^(-1) ** (-d ** a^(-1) - (f - d ** a^(-1) ** c) ** (i - g ** a^(-1) ** c - (h - g ** a^(-1) ** b) ** (e - d ** a^(-1) ** b)^(-1) ** (f - d ** a^(-1) ** c))^(-1) ** (-g ** a^(-1) + (h - g ** a^(-1) ** b) ** (e - d ** a^(-1) ** b)^(-1) ** d ** a^(-1))) - c ** (i - g ** a^(-1) ** c - (h - g ** a^(-1) ** b) ** (e - d ** a^(-1) ** b)^(-1) ** (f - d ** a^(-1) ** c))^(-1) ** (-g ** a^(-1) + (h - g ** a^(-1) ** b) ** (e - d ** a^(-1) ** b)^(-1) ** d ** a^(-1)))
```

I want to change the output to standard form of Mathematica like

```
Inverse[a].(1-b.Inverse[e-d.Inverse[a].b]...
```

Comment: This is tricky, especially if you want it to work with letters that will be substituted by matrices. The main trouble is that things like `a + b ** c` will be expanded incorrectly: `b**c` will be added entrywise to the entries `a`. We have an internal routine for doing that in NCAlgebra but I never thought it was good enough to be made public.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I am not familiar with NCAlgebra, the following seems to work:

```
result /. {inv -> Inverse, NonCommutativeMultiply -> Dot}
(* Inverse[
  a].(1 - b.Inverse[
     e - d.Inverse[
        a].b].(-d.Inverse[a] - (f - d.Inverse[a].c).Inverse[
        i - g.Inverse[a].c - (h - g.Inverse[a].b).Inverse[
           e - d.Inverse[a].b].(f - d.Inverse[a].c)].(-g.Inverse[
            a] + (h - g.Inverse[a].b).Inverse[
           e - d.Inverse[a].b].d.Inverse[a])) - 
   c.Inverse[
     i - g.Inverse[a].c - (h - g.Inverse[a].b).Inverse[
        e - d.Inverse[a].b].(f - d.Inverse[a].c)].(-g.Inverse[
         a] + (h - g.Inverse[a].b).Inverse[
        e - d.Inverse[a].b].d.Inverse[a])) *)
```

Note that NCAlgebra produces `inv[a]` when inverting `a`. This is formatted as $a^{-1}$, but the underlying structure is just `inv`. You can see this using [`FullForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html).